# Tensorflow: How to get Input and Output nodes from model graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a model (faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2018_01_28) with Tensorflow. I have a **".pb"** graph.

To make a frozen graph I need **Input and Output nodes**.

**How can I find it in the graph?**

I have got full list of nodes [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VictorDDT/uploadfiles/master/model_nodes.txt).

There no any nodes like 'Softmax', 'Placeholder' as it recommended in other posts.

Answer (score 0):

Use summarize graph which is a C++ build. My suggestion is you can use Docker to run summarize graph and get the input and output names of a trained model.See this link

[GITHUB LINK FOR GRAPH TRANSFORMATION TOOL(SUMMARIZE GRAPH)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md)

`bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph`
`bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph --in_graph=tensorflow_inception_graph.pb`